# The name 'FormMethod' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Out of a sudden, I started getting Razor errors:

The name 'FormMethod' does not exist in the current context 
The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

However, when I compile they disappear and application runs good, but im not able to make use of intellisense.